# How can I disable -Wcompare-distinct-pointer-types warning in clang?

Tags: objective-c, compiler-errors, clang, llvm, xcode7

I'm getting a compiler error,

> comparison of distinct pointer types ('OrgApacheXpathObjectsXObject *'
>   and 'OrgApacheXpathObjectsXNumber *')
>         [-Werror,**-Wcompare-distinct-pointer-types**]

Tried to disable it with **-Wno-incompatible-pointer-types** and that did not help. (**-Wno-compare-distinct-pointer-types** is not even a valid argument.)

On GCC there's no way to disable this warning evidently, just hoping Clang is somehow better?

I don't have control over the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**-Wno-compare-distinct-pointer-types** actually does work. The problem is that if you have any invalid compiler flags elsewhere in the line, then the whole line will be bad, not just the one flag that was bad.

Comment: It is also worth noting that the order of the options matters. For example "-Wno-covered-switch-default -Wcovered-switch-default" will not disable the warning but "-Wcovered-switch-default -Wno-covered-switch-default" will.

Answer (score 1):

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wincompatible-pointer-types"
...
your code
...
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Comment: Sorry, doesn't do the trick for me --- the warning still appears when I recompile. I compete an NSString*val = [myDictionary objectForKey:@"myKey"] against [NSNull null] - and the warning "Comparison of distinct pointer types ('NSString *' and 'NSNull * _Nonnull')" persists even within this pragma scope